# Do fans need to run on DC?

Tags: motor, ac, dc, fan

I recently took apart a wall outlet fan and saw that it works by using the magnetic field created by a coil of wire to spin a piece of metal. I wondered if this runs on DC or AC, and I thought if AC is constantly changing direction, wouldn't that also affect the magnetic field created, and make the fan spin back and forth? I was just wondering if you can somehow use AC to run a fan without having to convert it to DC.

Comment: Fans are just fancy motors.

Comment: I don't think so. I think it is an induction motor. Induction motors can't run on DC.

Comment: Most likely AC as it wouldn't make economic sense for them convert to DC in this application. But a photo of the insides would be useful. Also, you can measure with your voltmeter what the fan's motor actually gets. There a lot of types of [AC motors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC_motor).

Comment: Conversion of AC do DC and then re-synthesis to variable-voltage and frequency AC is an increasingly cost effective way to do motor speed control, however your typical box window fan accomplishes speed control with a selector switch between three or so distinct winding configurations.

Answer (score 1):

There is a motor called a *universal motor*, which can run on AC or DC.  It's a brush motor, and both the armature and the field are supplied from the same AC source.  So, when the polarity switches, both rotor and stator switch, maintaining the same magnetic relationship at any given time.  This type of motor is found in vacuum cleaners and other (typically noisy) appliances.

Answer (score 0):

Fans that plug into the wall use AC without having to convert it to DC. A couple of different methods are used to direct the magnetic field to make it behave like a rotating magnetic field.

Edit:

Induction motors are simple and inexpensive. Very simple methods are available to direct the magnetic field to get the motor started and give it a direction rather than standing still and vibrating back and forth. One starting method is to divide the windings into two groups. One group is given a different impedance. One way to do that is to use a different number of turns and likely a different wire size. Another way is to connect a capacitor in series. In some motors, one winding is just a closed loop of one or more turns that are not connected to the power source.

In an induction motor, the rotor needs no magnet because a circulating current is induced in the rotor by transformer action from the stator.

Answer (score 0):

The type of motor used in most fans is a [single phase synchronous motor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronous_motor). There are several poles wound around the stator. AC current causes the magnetic field to alternate between poles. This produces the rotating magnetic field to drive the rotor. The rotor has a stationary magnet on it which produces torque in the presence of the magnetic field. This type of motor is ideal for small fans because it runs directly on AC, and doesn't have any brushes. The catch is that it is synchronous. The angular velocity of the magnetic field is determined by the frequency of the AC power applied and the number of poles.

Edit: What you said about the motor spinning back and forth is absolutely true. This type of motor in general is not self starting. Very small synchronous motors can be self starting, but larger ones generally are not. There are different methods of starting synchronous motors, such as starting capacitors, extra windings, or electronic control.

Comment: They aren't synchronous motors, rather asynchronous or induction (same thing) motors. They don't have permanent magnets, rather squirel cage, more over you can't spin the synchronous motor without using a frequency inverter, no capacitor can be used for that.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič many synchronous motors operate without inverters.

Comment: @ChrisStratton But they need an additional device or method to start up, you can't just connect them to the grid with a switch.

Comment: Single phase induction motors are not self starting. A synchronous motor would generally self-start when connected to single-phase, but it would randomly start in either direction unless a starting mechanism is provided. However it would be extremely unusual for a simple plug-in fan to have a synchronous motor. That is what makes this answer pretty much useless.